# Remove item from session in Razor view when leaving the page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, session, razor

I need to clear an item from `System.Web.HttpSessionStateBase.Session` when navigate to any page. 
This is needed as we have fields that should be cleared when click on `navigate-to-page` menu item.
 Each item has `href` attribute that calls action method.
When I use sample below it shows an error- `Cannot implicitly convert type void to object`.

```
$('.navigate-to-page').on('click', function () {

   // @Session.Remove("ItemToRemoveKey");

});
```

**Edit 1**

@Hassen Ch mentioned that you cannot use razor code inside javascript, well, you acutally can! 
*Code that I currently have:*

```
$('.navigate-to-page').on('click', function () {
    @{
         this.Session.Remove("ItemToRemoveKey");                 
    }
});
```

The issues that I have **now**:
1. When I navigate to other pages, no click event is fired, although when I return to previous page, it first fires the action method and the click event.
2. The action method is called first, therefore view model is not up to date.

Comment: You cannot use Razor syntax with JQuery. Because obviously Razor generates code in server side, and Jquery is in client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it client side.

You might want to define an action and call it via ajax on click

Comment: Yes, it works! I needed to add `[HttpGet]` attribute to my action method and return null for it to work. Thanks.